# Why is onDraw(Canvas canvas) method of custom view not getting called in list adapter?

Tags: android

the whole code is like that

first is custom view class

```
public class AnimatedView extends View {
private static final String TAG="ANIMATEDVIEW";
    private Movie mMovie;
     private long mMoviestart;
    private InputStream is;
    private Context mContext;
public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext=context;
    is=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
    mMovie=Movie.decodeStream(is);
    //this.draw(context.getSystemService(Context.))
    this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    Log.v(TAG,"calling constructor of 2 params");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
    public void setImageId(int id){
is=mContext.getResources().openRawResource(id);
mMovie=Movie.decodeStream(is);
this.invalidate();
this.setWillNotDraw(false);
this.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);
    }
public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    is=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
    mMovie=Movie.decodeStream(is);
    Log.v(TAG,"calling constructor of 3 params");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public AnimatedView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    is=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
    mMovie=Movie.decodeStream(is);
    Log.v(TAG,"calling constructor of 1 params");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    super.onDraw(canvas);       
    final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    if (mMoviestart == 0) {
        mMoviestart = now;
    }
    int startTime = (int) (now - mMoviestart);
    int dur = 1;
    if (mMovie != null)
        dur = mMovie.duration();
    final int relTime = startTime % dur;
    mMovie.setTime(relTime);
    mMovie.draw(canvas, 10, 10);
    this.invalidate();
}
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Log.v(TAG,"On onMeasure==>");
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(
                parentWidth * 2, parentHeight);
    }

     }
```

Adapter code:

```
public class AnimAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<Item> piclist;
private int rowResID;

public AnimAdapter(Context mContext, List<Item> piclist, int rowResID) {
super();
this.mContext = mContext;
this.piclist = piclist;
this.rowResID = rowResID;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return piclist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return piclist.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pos;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Item imgAnimItm= piclist.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflate=(LayoutInflater)   mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v=inflate.inflate(rowResID, parent, false);
        TextView animTxtName= (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.helloTxt );
        if( animTxtName != null )
            animTxtName.setText( imgAnimItm.getName());
        AnimatedView animView= (AnimatedView)v.findViewById( R.id.anim_view );
        if( animView!= null )
            animView.setImageId(imgAnimItm.getId());
        return v;
}

 }
```

List Activity code:

```
public class CustomActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom);
    ArrayList<Item> alarmList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    Item a = new Item("Low memory", R.drawable.angel_pray_anim);
    alarmList.add(a);
    a = new Item("Process #345 stopped", R.drawable.anim_angry);
    alarmList.add(a);
    a = new Item("Low memory", R.drawable.engg_anim);
    alarmList.add(a);
    a = new Item("Process #456 stopped", R.drawable.finger_anim);
    alarmList.add(a);
    AnimAdapter AnimAdapter = new AnimAdapter(this, alarmList,
            R.layout.anim_row_layout);
    setListAdapter(AnimAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_custom, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

anim_row.xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/helloTxt"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TextView>

<com.example.customviewdemo.AnimatedView
    android:id="@+id/anim_view"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip" >
</com.example.customviewdemo.AnimatedView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="No items" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Item class:

```
public class Item {
private String name;
private int id;

public Item(String name, int id) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

This is entire code I tried to use custom view and display animated gif file in list view but onDraw() method of AnimatedView is not getting called so it's not displaying anything.

Why is onDraw() not getting called?

I also tried to add instance of AnimatedView directly in layout in adapter but same result.

Comment: How to do you know it's not being called?

Comment: Hi Simon, I put break point and run the app in debug mode but it didn't come up in method.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did anyone ever fix this?

Comment: I hasn't seen anybody solve this problem and I think it's not possible in Android platform. Otherwise skype(even latest hangout) like app could have include animated emoticons long back.